# load data from database on date selection

Tags: delphi-xe2, delphi-xe

I am trying to load database data by using dbplannercalender1.

```
procedure TForm1.DBPlannerCalendar1DaySelect(Sender: TObject;
  SelDate: TDateTime);
begin
with absQuery2 do
begin
  absQuery2.Close;
  absQuery2.sql.Clear;
  ABSQuery2.SQL.Text:='select * from log where date = :a1';
  ABSQUERY2.PARAMS.ParamByName('a1').value:= DBPlannerCalendar1.Date;
  ABSQuery2.ExecSQL;
end;
end;
```

I get the error "date string expected"YYYY-MM-DD",but "="found at line 1..."
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: What kind of SQL server are you connecting to?  Sql Server?  MySQL?  It looks like "date" has some special meaning, while you're expecting it to refer to a column of the log table.  What is the schema of the log table?   Maybe try  log.date  instead of  date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `AsDateTime` instead of `Value`, to let the driver convert it to the proper format:

```
AbsQuery2.Params.ParamByName('a1').AsDateTime := DBPlannerCalendar1.Date;
```

If Absolute doens't support `AsDateTime` for some reason, format the date yourself:

```
AbsQuery2.Params.ParamByName('a1').Value := 
    FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd`, DBPlannerCalendar1.Date);
```

The first method is the best choice, because it works more portably between database engines (it works for all of them, because the driverr does the formatting into the proper arrangement for dates). Using the second means that if the DB expects something different than `YYYY-MM-DD`, you have to change the code everywhere that uses dates.

Comment: Then you're not posting your actual SQL text, because there's no error there. (There was an error in my second sample in the `FormatDateTime` date format, though, that I've fixed.) Which one of the two solutions I posted did you try?

Comment: ABSQUERY2.PARAMS.ParamByName('a1').Value := FormatDateTime('YYYY-MM-DD', DBPlannerCalendar1.Date); does not work. I still get the same error.

Comment: Try the first option I gave you instead (the one I said you should choose in the first place, and explained why you should choose it in my last paragraph). `AbsQuery2.Params.ParamByName('a1').AsDateTime` instead of `Value`.

Comment: Then post your **real** SQL, because what you posted in your question isn't it. The SQL in your question would not raise that exception with either version of the code I posted, so you're not posting your real query text.

Comment: what do you mean by real ? That's all the code there is. All I want is to get data from the database depending on the day selected in the DBPlannerCalendar1

Comment: I mean exactly what I said in my last comment - the SQL you posted, used with the code I gave you, would not raise the error you're seeing. I know my code is correct (both ways) because I've used it a few thousand times, which means your SQL must be wrong. But the SQL you posted here will work, so you must not have posted your actual SQL. Is `date` the actual name of your column in the database? It's usually a reserved word in SQL databases.

Answer (score 1):

Use trunced value 
adoQuery.Parameters.paramByName('DataDal').value := trunc(edDate.Date);